# View inside other View (WPF/MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this UserControl called ControlButtonsView

```
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource MinimizeButton}" Command="{Binding MinimizeAppCommand}" Height="40" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    <Button Content="X" Style="{StaticResource ExitButton}" Command="{Binding ExitAppCommand}" Height="40" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

and ControlButtonsViewModel

```
class ControlButtonsViewModel
{
    private MainWindow _mainWindow;

    public ICommand MinimizeAppCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand ExitAppCommand { get; set; }

    public ControlButtonsViewModel(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;

        MinimizeAppCommand = new BaseICommand(MinimizeApp);
        ExitAppCommand = new BaseICommand(ExitApp);
    }

    public void MinimizeApp(object obj)
    {
        _mainWindow.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    public void ExitApp(object obj)
    {
        _mainWindow.Close();
    }
}
```

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
this.DataContext = new AppManagerViewModel();
```

AppManagerViewModel controls the switching between Views

What I want is to be able to use this ControlButtonsView with its ControlButtonsViewModel in multiple other Views, this view is a UserControl with a minimize and a maximize buttons and I want to use them in multiple Views, in LogInView, MenuView etc.

If there is an easier way to do this please tell me) Thank you.

Comment: _"If there is an easier way to do this"_: easier than what? You tagged your question _MVVM_. You are currently violating the pattern by adding view related logic to your view model. View model is a component that does not have any idea of the existence of a view: you are not allowed to pass a control to the view model and control its behavior. You add the view model to the control e.g. by setting the DataContext. The constructor of the view may request a view model but not the other way around. `DataContext = this.DataContext = new AppManagerViewModel();`does not make much sense, does it?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can add the UserControl to as many other controls you like. It's like using a TextBox.

Comment: Note, to improve performance and more important, to avoid memory leaks, your binding source (the view model class) must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Even if you don't raise the event.

Comment: The UI logic has to be moved to the UserControl `ControlButtonsView`. The control then must implement the commands as routed commands. Since it appears you are only interested in controlling the MainWindow, the logic including the routed commands should rather be moved to this class. Routed command are static, so they can be referenced globally. MainWindow can handle every command invocation as long the command was invoked by a child

Comment: I have a UserControl view that has 2 buttons in it (minimize and exit) and in my view model of that UserControl i have 2 command buttons for those buttons, the problem is that I can use the view in other views but then that UserControl does not bind to its view model commands.

Comment: @BionicCode I want to have this UserControl in LogInView, MenuView and other views, this UserControl minimizes or exits the application, I just don't want to implement the minimize and exit commands of the buttons in every view

Comment: @BionicCode Sorry I wrote it wrong, I did edit it, should be like this -> this.DataContext = new AppManagerViewModel(); and in AppManagerViewModel I have the viewmodel instances of the views I want to switch between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` logic does not belong to the view model. View model does not care about UI.  You must always implement the view model pretending like there is no UI, only a model.

Therefore having a reference of `MainWindow` in you view model will lead to a tight coupling of the application to the view/UI.

The goal of MVVM is to remove this tight coupling. Obviously, due to the tight coupling you have introduced, you are currently not implementing the MVVM pattern (you are implementing it wrong).
For example, you won't be able to test the view model without creating a view.

Injecting the view as constructor dependency makes it even worse.

Because the commands execute UI logic (close, minimize), they have to be moved to a control - to the view component from a MVVM point of view.

To make those commands available throughout your view or globally relative to the actual visual tree, you should implement those commands as routed commands e.g. on your `MainWindow`, which you want to control via commanding.

Since [routed commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routedcommand?view=net-5.0#remarks) are static, they can be referenced by every other control.  Because they are routed, they can be used everywhere in the same visual tree that the command target (the `MainWindow`) belongs to.

Internally the command, once executed, will raise a routed event which will traverse the visual tree until it finds a handler.

[Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

In your case, `MainWindow` will register the Execute and CanExecute handler to close or minimize *itself*.

The following example implements only the logic to close the `Window`.
You can follow the pattern to provide additional logic e.g. to maximize the `Window`:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly RoutedUICommand CloseWindowRoutedCommand = new RoutedUICommand(
    "Closes the application.", 
    nameof(MainWindow.CloseWindowRoutedCommand), 
    typeof(MainWindow));


  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.CommandBindings.Add(
      new CommandBinding(MainWindow.CloseWindowRoutedCommand, 
        ExecuteCloseWindow, 
        CanExecuteCloseWindow));
  }

  private void CanExecuteCloseWindow(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) => e.CanExecute = true;

  private void ExecuteCloseWindow(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) => Close();
}
```

**ControlButtonsView.xaml**

```
<Grid>
  <-- ICommand traverse visual tree until handler(s) is found -->
  <Button Content="X" Command="{x:static MainWindow.CloseWindowRoutedCommand}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you, so if i understood correctly, i don't need ViewModels for UserControls that i plan to use multiple times globally right? i just do it the way you showed

Comment: Not exactly. I say you are not allowed to handle UI logic or to establish a dependency to the view in your view model - doing so does not conform to MVVM. It will introduce a lot of problems, that you wanted to avoid, which is the reason you chose MVVM. You can use view models for your controls, but don't mess with the responsibilities. When your view model can exist without a view, then you are on a good way.

Comment: Usually you say, the view model has no idea that there is a UI and a user. The view model only knows and talks to the model. Doing it the way I showed you does solve this problem right? We moved responsibilities related to the UI back to the UI. Now the UI can handle its own logic. UI logic is for example handling visibility, layout, appearance (e.g. colors), animations and user interaction or generally handling controls and their behavior.

Comment: Okay, so when I used _mainWindow.Close(); (Which is UI logic rigt? because it does stuff to the UI) in my ViewModel I was violating the MVVM pattern and it was incorrect, my ViewModels should only do the data logic and hold the variables  that the view binds to?

Comment: Correct. View model gets data from the model and presents it to view via data binding. View model doesn't access database or files or uses services directly as this is part of the model. View can send data to view model via data binding or invoke commands to execute an operation. Model manages data itself (e.g. reading/writing from/to database or files or posting HTTP requests) and contains the business logic. View only talks to/knows the view model and view model only knows the model.  Model knows nobody.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful )

Answer (score 0):

1. In `AppManagerViewModel`, add a property of `ControlButtonsViewModel`.

   `public ControlButtonsViewModel ControlButtonsViewModel {get; set;}`
2. In the constructor of `AppManagerViewModel`, add
   `ControlButtonsViewModel = new ControlButtonsViewModel();`
3. In Xaml of `AppManagerView`,

   <ControlButtonsView DataContext="{Binding ControlButtonsViewModel}" ... />

Comment: I did that but this did not fix my problem. this just allowed me to use the UserControl but the bindings of the 2 buttons can not find the commands.